# jquery prepend to div without scrolling to top in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

While scrolling a div from the bottom to the top on mobile devices, I am trying to add fluid pagination. To do this I am using `$('#container').prepend(html)` which adds the next page, however after this is done the scroll position jumps to the top instead of staying at the last scroll position.

I tried to fix this by setting the new scroll position to the old position after the content is prepended, however this interrupts the scrolling as it first jumps up to the top of the div while exposing the new content, and then jumping back down to the previous scroll position. This is especially noticeable on mobile devices where I have to fire the scroll position adjustment in a timeout after the prepend, because without the timeout it does not work at all.

Is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Your problem is that you probably prepend when the scroll is at 0 vertically. Am i right? If that so, prepend when you're at 100 or 50 px so as not to jump to top.

Comment: I prepend before 300px, still jumps in mobile

Comment: Can you share the basic code so i can test? I can't try it without. Just the append part and the container, will append an empty div or something.